# When does boost::deque allocate/deallocate?

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost, memory-management, deque

I've tried to find some guarantees on allocation/deallocation behaviour of [`boost::container::deque`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/container/deque.html) but couldn't find. My assumptions are as follows.

1. No block will be allocated if there is a free one.
2. It keeps all the freed blocks, so an allocated block will be deallocated only after `shrink_to_fit`?
3. When there is no room for a new item a new block will be allocated. If there is no room for the handle of the newly allocated block, all the block handles will be reallocated.

Are these assumptions correct?

Answer (score 0):

> When does boost::deque allocate/deallocate?

Memory will be deallocated when the container is destroyed. Unused memory may be deallocated when the container is shrunk. Otherwise allocation and deallocation are not documented and thus details are up to the implementation of the library.

> 1. No block will be allocated if there is a free one.

This is a reasonable expectation, but it is not guaranteed by the documentation.

> 2. It keeps all the freed blocks, so an allocated block will be deallocated only after shrink_to_fit?

This is also not guaranteed by the documentation. Note that unlike vector, deque can satisfy its complexity requirements even if it does deallocate early.

> 3. When there is no room for a new item a new block will be allocated. If there is no room for the handle of the newly allocated block, all the block handles will be reallocated.

Also not guaranteed by the documentation.  It is however reasonable to expect that memory will be allocated when there is no free space available.

Comment: boost's behavior is not implementation defined, and it is one of the motivations behind `boost::container`.

Comment: @Vahagn if it isn't defined by documentation, then it is up to the choices of the implementation. The implementation of the boost library; not the language implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/hPHs98Z7X-g/EgzTBkVvCgAJ) and checked [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xhKboY), 2nd assumption is incorrect for `boost::container::deque` (as well as for `std::deque` implementation of all the compilers).

It deallocates early! Btw, if there is no way to prevent it, then I can't get the purpose of providing `boost::container::deque::shrink_to_fit`.